# Implement main server loop in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

What is the generally accepted way to implement the main loop of a server that needs to wait on a heterogeneous set of events?  That is the server should wait (not busywait) until one of the following occurs:

- new socket connection
- data available on an existing socket
- OS signal
- third-party library callbacks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're thinking in terms of a C paradigm with a single thread, nonblocking I/O, and a select() call.

You can manage to write something like that in Haskell, but Haskell has much more to offer:

- [lightweight threads](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent.html)
- safe and efficient concurrent data primitives like [Mvar](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html) and [Chan](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html)
- the Big Gun:  [Software Transactional Memory](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Software_transactional_memory)

I recommend you fork a new thread for every separate point of contact with the outside world, and keep everything coordinated with STM.

Answer (score 2):

Use `takeMVar` and `putMVar` to synchronize between threads. They generally block the thread if operation is not permitted.
Read [ghc docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html).

Comment: Or `Chan`.  I really like `Chan`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to make it clear I think the two solutions posted first are better than this one for the specific problem you have, but here's a way to solve the type of problem you presented.

A simple way round this is to take your definitions like

```
data SocketConn = ....
data DataAvail = ...
data OSSignal = ...
data Callback = ...
```

and define the unsimplified version of

```
data ServerEvent = Sok SocketConn | Dat DataAvail | Sig OSSignal | Call Callback

handleEvent :: ServerEvent -> IO ()
handleEvent (Soc s) = ....
handleEvent (Dat d) = ....
handleEvent (Sig o) = ....
handleEvent (Call c) = ....
```

Like I say, read up on the other answers!

Comment: You shouldn't decry this answer so much; it's a legitimate way to do things. And it *does* answer the underlying generalized question, which is, "how does one handle the possibility of different shapes of inputs that all go into the same slot?". The answer is "use a tagged union", as you suggested.

Comment: @DanBurton OK, I've toned down the "don't do this" to "the other solutions are better for your specitic problem"

Answer (score 0):

Software Transactional Memory (STM) is the main way to do a multi-way wait.

However, by the looks of things, in your case you probably just want to spawn a seperate Haskell thread for each task, and let each such thread block while there's nothing happening.

You wouldn't want to create a thousand OS threads, but a thousand Haskell threads is no trouble at all.

(If these threads need to coordinate from time to time, then again, STM is probably the simplest, most reliable way to do that.)